# math range error в функции sin

Tags: python, функции, математика

```
import math
def L(a, b,eps):
    list_of_L = [] 
    min = 0
    while a <= b:
        min = math.fabs(2*a - math.cos(a))
        list_of_L.append(min)
        a+=eps
        list_of_L.sort()
    return list_of_L[len(list_of_L)-1]
def f(x):
    return math.pow(x,2)-math.sin(x) #math range error
def F(list,x):
    min = f(x)
    list.append(min)
    list.sort()
    first_element = list[0]
    return first_element
minimums_of_func = []    
#a = float(input('Введіть a: '))
#b = float(input('Введіть b: '))
a = 0
b = 3.1415926535
#eps = float(input('Введіть точність обчислення: '))
eps = 0.01
l = L(a,b,eps)
h = (2*eps)/l
n = int(math.ceil((b-a)/h))
print(n)
x = []
x.append(a + h/2)
i = 1
while i <= n - 2:
    x_previous = x[i-1]
    x.append(x[i-1] + h + (f(x_previous) - F(minimums_of_func,x_previous))/l)
    i+=1
x.append(min(x[len(x)-2]+h+(f(x[len(x)-2]) - F(minimums_of_func,x[len(x)-2]))/l,b))
y_min = F(minimums_of_func,x[n-1])
i = 0
while i < len(x)-1:
    if(f(x[i]) == y_min):
       print(x[i],y_min)
       break
    i+=1
X = []
X.append(a + h/2)
i = 1
while i <= n - 2:
    X.append(X[i-1] + h)
    i+=1
X.append(min(X[len(X)-2]+h,b))
i = 0
ff = []
while i < n-1:
    ff.append(f(X[i]))
    i+=1
ff.sort()
y_min = ff[0]
i = 0
while i < len(X)-1:
    if(f(X[i]) == y_min):
       print(X[i],y_min)
       break
    i+=1
```

Comment: "Вопрос", состоящий только из одного кода (в котором к тому же много лишнего), без сопровождающего текста, заслуживает минуса.

Comment: @Эникейщик, полностью согласен с тем что приведено слишком много лишнего кода, но вопрос тем не менее содержит __воспроизводимый__ пример. Поэтому для поддержания нейтралитета ставлю `+` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях полезно использовать обработчики исключений.

**Пример**:

```
def f(x):
    ret = 0
    try:
        ret = math.pow(x,2)
    except OverflowError:
        print(f'math.pow({x},2) has failed with the "OverflowError" exception!')
        raise
    try:
        ret -= math.sin(x)
    except OverflowError:
        print(f'math.sin({x}) has failed with the "OverflowError" exception!')
        raise
    return ret
```

**Вывод на печать:**

```
1144
math.pow(1.0576084371387694e+233,2) has failed with the "OverflowError" exception!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
...
```

**Вывод:** вы пытаетесь возвести во вторую степень число состоящее из 233 цифр - модуль `math` вам намекает, что это многовато...
;-)